# How to set content-length in android?

Tags: java, android, content-length

I want to get content size by `request.getContentLength()` in server client JSP page.
But request.getContentLength() always return -1, i do not why?

Android snippet code:

```
URL uri = new URL(actionUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
//conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(100);
conn.setConnectTimeout(setTimeOut>0?setTimeOut:timeoutConnection);
conn.setReadTimeout(setTimeOut>0?setTimeOut:timeoutConnection);  
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

//conn.setRequestProperty("content-length", "10");
//conn.addRequestProperty("content-length", "20");
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(30);

conn.setRequestProperty("Charsert", ENCODING);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
                + ";boundary=" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
conn.connect();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(100)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode%28int%29) that will effectively enable the [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) in chunks of 100 bytes when the content-lenght is unknown in advance.

Use [conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int len)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFixedLengthStreamingMode%28int%29) if you know in advance the length of the content you are going to send in the body of the request.