# Unable to send a string from app to servlet using outputStreamWriter()

Tags: java, android, http, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to send a small String over from my app to a Java servlet:

```
//Send user mobile number to the server.
EditText cinMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
String inputVal = cinMobile.getText().toString();

URL mobileurl = new URL(url);
URLConnection connection = mobileurl.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(inputVal);
out.close();
```

The servlet is supposed to receive the value through doPost():

```
//Accept the phone number form the app
int length = request.getContentLength();                                
byte[] input = new byte[length];                        
ServletInputStream sin = request.getInputStream();      
int c, count = 0;

while((c = sin.read(input, count, input.length-count)) != -1) {
    count = +c;                                          
}                                                           

sin.close();

String receivedString = new String(input);              
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

System.out.print(receivedString);
```

But when I run my command and try to send the String over, I get `Negative array size exception` on the servlet side for the line `byte[] input = new byte[length];`:

```
Feb 01, 2014 2:06:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [project_server.Login] in context with path [/project_server] threw exception
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at project_server.Login.doPost(Login.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here but the error implies that it is not receiving any string. 
LogCat shows no error for the app side.

Comment: what value you are getting in request.getContentLength() in log?

Comment: @KamleshArya -1; pretty much what the error is saying.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121677/how-to-set-content-length-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure what is wrong here but the error implies that it is not receiving any string.

No, the error implies that you're trying to create an array with a negative length. That implicates these lines:

```
int length = request.getContentLength();                                
byte[] input = new byte[length];
```

Presumably the `Content-Length` header isn't being set, so `getContentLength()` is returning -1. You should be able to handle that - just read from the input stream until `read()` returns a non-positive number. For example, you can copy the data using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Alternatively, you could just use a `StringBuilder` and create an `InputStreamReader` around the input stream:

```
char[] buffer = new char[8192];
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
    int charsRead;
    while ((charsRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        builder.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
    }
}
String text = builder.toString();
```

Note how I've specified UTF-8 as the input encoding - you should specify the same encoding when *writing* the data too. At the moment you're relying on the platform default encoding being the same on the client as the server, which is a bad idea.